# Passing parameter from JSTL to servlet through <a href> and jstl tags

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jstl, href

So this is the code i'm using to send the parameter "idemp" that contains the value `${masession.idemp}`

```
<a href="<c:url value="/consultertickets">
                <c:param name="idemp" value="${masession.idemp}"/>
         </c:url>">
<img src="<c:url value="/inc/liste.png"></c:url>" alt="consulter tickets" />
</a>
```

when redirected to the servlet "/consultertickets" the browser URL shows:

```
http://localhost:4040/monprojet2/consultertickets?idemp=64
```

so the parameter is passed and working but the method used to obviously GET and not POST, which is the method i'm using in the servlet, here's the servlet's code.

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns= {"/consultertickets"})

public class ConsulterTickets extends HttpServlet {

private String VUE = "/WEB-INF/ListeTickets.jsp";

@EJB
private TicketDao ticketDao;
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(VUE).forward(request, response);
}


protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    CreationTicketForm ticketform = new CreationTicketForm(ticketDao);
    List<Ticket> lticket = ticketform.recupererTickets(request);

    boolean resultat;
    if(lticket.isEmpty())
    {
        //resultat="Vous n'avez soumit aucun ticket";
        resultat = false;
        request.setAttribute("resultat", resultat);
        this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/ListeTickets2.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }else{
        //String VUE = "/ListeTickets.jsp";
        resultat=true;
        request.setAttribute("resultat", resultat);
        request.setAttribute("lticket", lticket);
        this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(VUE).forward(request, response);
    }
}

}
```

is there any way to pass a parameter to a servlet through POST method, without going through the `<form></form>`

Comment: why do you want post method, get method is suitable to use in here.

Comment: I want the parameters to be invisible in the URL;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1:**

Modifying `doGet` method

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    //this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(VUE).forward(request, response);
    doPost(request, response);
}
```

**Solution 2:**

Remove the `doGet()` and change `doPost()`  to `service()`

**Edit1:**

See, `Hyperlinks`(`<a>` tag) are meant to send **GET** request but not **POST**.

So, if you want to achieve sending **POST** request using **Hyperlink** there is no straight way. But, `Javascript` can be your help.

Using `Javascript` you can guide `<a>` to send **POST** request along with the help of `<form>`.

I just modified your code little bit. This should help you.

```
<a href="javascript:document.getElementById('form1').submit()">
    <img src="<c:url value="/inc/liste.png"></c:url>" alt="consulter tickets" />
</a>

<form action="<c:url value="/consultertickets"/>" method="post" id="form1">
    <input type="hidden" name="idemp" value="${masession.idemp}"/>
</form>
```

Comment: But i am still able to see the parameter passed in the browser's URL.